# Why do certain commands not show up when you type "help" in cmd.exe?

Tags: windows, command-line

For instance, netstat. This doesn't show up when you type help, but `netstat /?` does provide the information.

Are there any other commands that will not get listed?

Also, the command `netstat /? > netstat.txt` won't work. Any idea why?
The netstat.txt file is created but remains empty.

I have write-permission on the map and the CMD.EXE is running as admin.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`netstat.exe` is a separate executable that lives in C:\Windows\system32 (or at least it does on XP), rather than being a command within `cmd.exe`.

There will be a large number of other executables in this folder (and others in the Windows tree) that won't show up when you type `help` from within `cmd.exe`.

Comment: Would this explain why I can't parse the /? output of those commands to textfiles?

Comment: Use "netstat /? 2>netstat.txt " . The usage information is sent to stderr, not stdout.

Answer (score 2):

(I was going to answer this, but then I did some research for you and this is not what I first thought, so +1 as I have learnt a bit here!)

When you type `help`, it launches C:\Windows\SysWOW64\help.exe (or guessing, C:\Windows\System32\help.exe on 32-bit Windows)

I guess that listing **EVERY** executables would simply result in a huge list that most people will never read, so they only list built-in functions of the command prompt (`if`, `for`, `goto` etc.) and other commands which are generally used all the time.

FYI, if you want to see what is a "built in" command and what is a program, you can create a empty folder and navigate to it, then type

```
path=0
```

next, try any of the commands, if like typing `if` works, it is built-in, if typing help does not work, you know it was a command located somewhere else (again +1, I thought help was always a built-in command!)

Comment: It'll always run help.exe in `C:\windows\system32\help.exe` unless you're using the 32-bit cmd.exe on 64-bit Windows, since SysWOW64 is for 32-bit binaries. And the term for those "built-in" things is [*internal command*](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-internal.html) which can be checked simply by running `where command` and see no file output

Answer (score 2):

I assume most (if not all) of the commands listed under cmd.exe's help are basic/internal commands which are built-in cmd.exe directly.

For instance, try and look for a file named `del.exe` or `del.com`, or even a `dir.exe` or `dir.com` -- chances are that you won't find it (try: `dir /s LookForThisFile.ext`). I bet 10$ that most if not all the commands listed under help are 'internal' to cmd and not a binary by itself.

This way of doing things is also used with bash, where help is used to get help on pretty much any keyword provided by the bash scripting language.

Comment: you can run `for /f %f in ('help') do @where %f` to get which commands in help are internal or external and count accordingly. In my case I got 57 internal commands and 40 external ones