# Does help in Windows 10 Command Prompt display all commands

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, cmd.exe

I am learning the Windows command prompt, and I was wondering if there are any additional commands that do not appear when inputting "help."

Thanks!

[First page of "help" command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4mtV.png)

[Second and last page of "help" command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dKOZ.png)

Comment: There are commands like NETSH that do not show up in help.  I do not think "help" was meant to be completely comprehensive.

Comment: https://www.lifewire.com/list-of-command-prompt-commands-4092302 There are quite a few commands, and out of those most people will only use a few. There are quite a few on this list that are not in the screenshots.

Comment: obviously not [Why do certain commands not show up when you type "help" in cmd.exe?](https://superuser.com/q/62220/241386)

Comment: why are you linking to pictures of text? ... add the actual text instead

Comment: more complete list on [SS64](https://ss64.com/nt/) (not all commands available on all Windows versions)